# If $(I -0.4A)^{-1}=I -\alpha A$ then $\alpha$ is

Tags: matrices

If $A$ is idempotent matrix satisfying $(I -0.4A)^{-1}=I -\alpha A$ where $I$ is the unit matrix of same order of that of  and $A \ne 0$ , then value of $\alpha$ is

$$(I -0.4A)^{-1}=I -\alpha A$$
$$I^{-1} -0.4A^{-1}=I -\alpha A$$
Multiply by $A$
$$A- 0.4 I =A-\alpha A$$

What I have done wrong ,I think my second step is wrong .

Comment: $$(I-0.4A)^{-1}\stackrel{?!}=I^{-1}-0.4A^{-1}\\ \text{It hurts}$$

Comment: Your first step is wrong. You cannot distribute the $^{-1}$ into the brackets so easily. Try it for $1\times1$ matrices (also known as real numbers) and see for yourself: $\frac1{1-a}$ is certainly not $\frac11-\frac1a$ for any real number $a$.

Comment: How to evaluate that  expression

Comment: How would you put $\frac{1}{1-0.4x}=1-\alpha x$ into a better-looking form?

Comment: Note that $B^{-1}$ basically means $\frac1B$, except we don't use fractions with matrices for two reasons: $B^{-1}C$ and $CB^{-1}$ might be different matrices, so $\frac CB$ is ambiguous, and it's too easy to forget that $B^{-1}$ might not exist.

Comment: When transpose is in power something like this is allowed .

Comment: Transposition is linear, powers (positive and negative ones, unless the exponent is $1$) are not.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Thanks for clearing the things .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now $(I-0.4A)^{-1}=I-\alpha A$ implies $I=(I-\alpha A)(I-0.4A)=I-(0.4+\alpha-0.4\alpha)A$ as $A$ is idempotent.

Therefore, $0.4-0.4\alpha+\alpha=0$. Now solve for $\alpha$.

Comment: What is the point of spelling out every single step until the very end, and then leaving a trivial computation as an exercise?

Comment: For a beginner, I think it is better to write exactly what I have written. If you notice, I have explicitly used two points: inverse and idempotence, which,I think are not very trivial for a beginner.